# Upload api fails and throws below exception when file is more than 3MB

Tags: box-api, box

I am having issue with box-sdk (https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2) upload API.
Issue :
When try to upload large file (more than 3MB) (file less than 3mb works great.)
Upload api fails and throws below exception.

Error :

ToString : 
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at XXXX.Program.d__34.MoveNext() in d:\Gaurav\TFS\XXXX\XXXX\Program.cs:line 319
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.<---

StackTrace :
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at XXXX.Program.d__34.MoveNext() in d:\Gaurav\TFS\XXXX\XXXX\Program.cs:line 319

InnerException : 
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. TIME : 2014-05-28 04:55:59 PM

Code that is generating error :

```
using (Task<BoxFile> uploadTask = boxClient.FilesManager.UploadAsync(boxFileRequest, spStream))
{
    BoxFile newFile = uploadTask.Result;
}
```

Comment: I had this same issue reported by a user, but I've not been able to reproduce it. I asked them to install Fiddler and take an HTTP trace of the failure. When they started logging the HTTP traffic, the problem suddenly went away!

Comment: The other thing to check is the max file size allowed on the account, or their remaining quota.

Comment: Thanks John and Peter,
1. File size : I have ent account so max file size is 2gb
2. Did Fiddler and looks like httpClient timeout issue, also confirmed from box.com team, they are working on issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use timeout parameter in UploadAsync method:

```
boxFile = Client.FilesManager.UploadAsync(req, fs, null, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)).Result;
```

Comment: I had the same issue -- small files (~1 MB) uploaded fine; large files (> 10 MB) got the task cancelled exception.  All the suggested fixes said you really needed to "chunk" your file and upload it in pieces.  You suggestion is a LOT easier and works (so far) great!  Thanks!